# Why does zsh navigation behave differently in the VS Code terminal vs macOS terminal?

Tags: macos, zsh, visual-studio-code, terminal.app, oh-my-zsh

When I am using zsh in the inbuilt VS Code terminal, I can:

a) use the up and down arrow keys to navigate through my command history when typing a command:

[zsh command navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OsG5.png)

b) use all arrow keys to navigate through available directories:

[zsh dir navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDkV.png)

However, when I use arrow keys in the macOS terminal... well, I'm not exactly sure what decisions it is making, but it appears to sometimes be changing directory to the parent directory (up key) or to the first child directory alphabetically (down key):

[zsh macos navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbGnx.png)

But also, sometimes it seems to jump to a recently used directory without an immediate familial relationship.

The desired behaviour is the VS Code behaviour. I am not sure how and why they would differ, given there is only one .zshrc file.

My plugins are:

```
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting fast-syntax-highlighting zsh-autocomplete history dirhistory web-search)
```

Thank you kindly!